# Geotagging with cwac-camera

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'd like to use cwac-camera for taking photos.

However, I need to capture also location of the place where the photo was taken

On my device, I set location on and run the demo provided as part of the library.

The captured photo didn't contain the gps-related information in its EXIF metadata.

When I tried then default camera app, the photo captured in this way contained the location in its EXIF metadata.

So, it seems cwac-camera is not storing the location into EXIF metadata.

**Is it possible to activate storing of the location into EXIF somehow?**

If not, how would you recommend capturing the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, it seems cwac-camera is not storing the location into EXIF metadata.

Correct.

> Is it possible to activate storing of the location into EXIF somehow?

You are welcome to find out the location of the device by whatever means you choose. You are then welcome to call appropriate methods on `Camera.Parameters`, like `setGpsLatitude()`, to supply that information to the `Camera`, and see if that works. 
In the current API, a likely place to do this work is in [`adjustPictureParameters()` on your `CameraHost`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#arbitrary-photo-configuration).

It's possible that I may need to amend the library to retain those EXIF headers through the `ImageCleanupTask`, if they are not already being retained.